# How to invoke NetBeans asking the user for a restart?

Tags: netbeans, restart

I'm looking to prompt the user to restart NetBeans after they have executed something. I'd like to reuse the existing architecture in NetBeans where the restart dialog remains in the bottom right corner and NetBeans restarts when the user clicks on it. Is this a publicly available API? And if so, how do I invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more searching on the NetBeans forums, I came across a Geertjan Wierlenga blog on the **NotificationDisplayer** API, which is exactly what I was looking for.